# FacebookStreamHttpClient not found

Tags: facebook-php-sdk

I'm sorry, I'm noob in PHP and I feel like asking a very basic question. Anyway a can't find the answer. I'm trying to ask Facebook if a person likes a facebook page. I've seen in the SDK that it's done with this code:

```
    $request = new FacebookRequest(
            $session,
            'GET',
            '/me/likes/<page_id'
    );
```

But when I try to do it, I get the following error:

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookStreamHttpClient' not found in (...)/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php on line 161

Sounds like Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookStreamHttpClient is not loaded. Anyway, I think it should be loaded by acebook/FacebookRequest, isn't it?

I already loaded the following files:

```
        require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );

    use Facebook\FacebookSession;
    use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
    use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
    use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
    use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
    use Facebook\GraphObject;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure you include those classes in your code:

```
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );

use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurl;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
```